# Kivy Python edit Label text from another class

Tags: python, kivy

I have two screens.
The first screen has a "Play" button that sends me to the "PlayScreen".
The second screen has a Label and two buttons;
Button "NewRandom": loads a random number from `SomeApp.RandomGen()`,
Button "Clear": Clears

What I would like to happen is that `initiate_random_number()` executes as soon as the buttons are created.

However, `App.get_running_app().root.ids.play_screen.random_num.text` is `None` because I'm guessing some ids dictionary under the hood is still not built?

Is there anyway I can access the Label from this `RandomNumber` class?

thanks.

Python app:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

import numpy as np


class MainWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class PlayScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlayScreen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WindowManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        main_window = ObjectProperty(None)
        play_screen = ObjectProperty(None)        

class RandomNumber(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RandomNumber, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cols = 2

        self.add_widget(Button(text='NewRandom', on_release=self.on_release))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Clear', on_release=self.on_release))

    def initiate_random_number(self):
        random_num = str(SampleApp.RandomGen())
        App.get_running_app().root.ids.play_screen.random_label.text = random_num 

    def on_release(self, btn):
        if btn.text == 'NewRandom':
           random_num = str(SampleApp.RandomGen())
           App.get_running_app().root.ids.play_screen.random_label.text = random_num 
        else:
           App.get_running_app().root.ids.play_screen.random_label.text = ''

#kv = Builder.load_file('sample.kv')

class SampleApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SampleApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        sm = WindowManager()
        return sm

    def RandomGen(self):
        return np.random.randint(100)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SampleApp().run()
```

kv:

```
<WindowManager>:
    id: window_manager
    main_window: main_window
    play_screen: play_screen
    
    MainWindow:
        id: main_window
        name: "main_window"
        manager: window_manager      
    PlayScreen:
        id: play_screen
        name: "play_screen"
        manager: window_manager    

<MainWindow>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text: "Play"
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "play_screen"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

<PlayScreen>:
    random_label: random_label
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            id: random_label
            #text: #TODO: show the output of initiate_random_number or Button
        RandomNumber:
        Button:
            text: "Back!"
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

the solution should give me a way to call the `random_label` via python and not just Kivy.

Comment: Your posted code is full of obvious errors that are not related to your question. (`GridLayout` is not correctly imported, the `super()` method of `RandomNumber` refers to an undefined class, ...). Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnAnderson apologies about the bad copy paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `initiate_random_number()` to run before the `PlayScreen` `Buttons` are displayed (although your code only has one `Button`), you can define an `on_enter()` method in the `PlayScreen` class:

```
def on_enter(self, *args):
    RandomNumber.initiate_random_number()
```

However, this requires a couple other changes. Some methods need to redefined as `static` and the access to the `random_label` must be corrected:

```
@staticmethod
def initiate_random_number():
    random_num = str(SomeApp.RandomGen())
    App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('play_screen').ids.random_label.text = random_num
```

Another method in the `App` that needs to be static:

```
@staticmethod
def RandomGen():
    return np.random.randint(100)
```

Comment: I believe my code has two buttons. `self.add_widget(Button(text='NewRandom', on_release=self.on_release))`
        `self.add_widget(Button(text='Clear', on_release=self.on_release))`

Comment: Your `RandomNumber` class is not added to your GUI anywhere, so those `Buttons` do not appear anywhere.

Comment: I'm still getting used to Kivy - really sorry. Edited the above code so everything should work. Trying out your solution on my end.

Comment: It works! I got rid of the `Builder.load_file('sample.kv')` and replaced it with `sm = WindowManager()` which meant your  `App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('play_screen').ids.random_label.text = random_num` needed to be `App.get_running_app().root.ids.play_screen.random_label.text = random_num`. All this is fine! Will post full code below. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Formalising @John Anderson solution above:

Python:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

import numpy as np


class MainWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class PlayScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlayScreen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        RandomNumber.initiate_random_number()

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WindowManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # main_window = ObjectProperty(None)
        # play_screen = ObjectProperty(None)        

class RandomNumber(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RandomNumber, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cols = 2

        self.add_widget(Button(text='NewRandom', on_release=self.on_release))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Clear', on_release=self.on_release))
        
    @staticmethod
    def initiate_random_number():
        random_num = str(SampleApp.RandomGen())
        App.get_running_app().root.ids.play_screen.random_label.text = random_num 

    def on_release(self, btn):
        if btn.text == 'NewRandom':
           random_num = str(SampleApp.RandomGen())
           App.get_running_app().root.ids.play_screen.random_label.text = random_num 
        else:
           App.get_running_app().root.ids.play_screen.random_label.text = ''

#kv = Builder.load_file('sample.kv')

class SampleApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SampleApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        sm = WindowManager()
        return sm
    
    @staticmethod
    def RandomGen():
        return np.random.randint(100)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SampleApp().run()
```

kv:

```
<WindowManager>:
    id: window_manager
    main_window: main_window
    play_screen: play_screen
    
    MainWindow:
        id: main_window
        name: "main_window"
        manager: window_manager      
    PlayScreen:
        id: play_screen
        name: "play_screen"
        manager: window_manager    

<MainWindow>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text: "Play"
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "play_screen"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

<PlayScreen>:
    random_label: random_label
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            id: random_label
            #text: #TODO: show the output of initiate_random_number or Button
        RandomNumber:
        Button:
            text: "Back!"
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "main_window"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```